# R Data file not converting to Stata file

Tags: r, stata

I am getting this error. Cannot figure out why? Any advise?

```
library(foreign)
x <- data.frame(a = "", b = 1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
write.dta(x, 'x.dta')
Error in write.dta(x, "x.dta") : 
 4 arguments passed to .Internal(nchar) which requires 3
```

Comment: Also could try the `readstata13` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [haven package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/haven/index.html) works much better than foreign in this case as it will read strings (including empty strings) as string values.

```
library( haven )
x <- data.frame( a = "", b = 1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE )
write_dta( x, 'x.dta' )
```

Alternatively, if you pass parameter a a value when creating the data frame, instead of an empty string, foreign will be fine.

```
x <- data.frame( a = "a", b = 1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE )
write.dta( x,"y.dta" )
```

As you're using an older version of Stata, haven is the way to go, as you can specify the version of Stata you wish the dta file to be compatible with.

```
write_dta( x, 'x.dta', version = 13 )
```

Comment: dta too modern
    File /Users/veeresh/Documents/R projects/superstars/allstarsstata1.dta is from a more
    recent version of Stata.

Comment: I am getting that error when I open the file, my stata is 13

Comment: I am still getting the same error even with the new code. I don't know why. Any idea?

Comment: I've appended my answer, have a look at the last line and use the version parameter.